# How can I replay a table in Deephaven?

Tags: python, real-time

I have a Deephaven table with some data.  I want to add timestamps to it and play it back in real-time in Python.  What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Deephaven's TableReplayer class allows you to replay table data.  In order to construct a TableReplayer, you need to specify a start time and end time in Deephaven's DateTime format.  The start and end times correspond to those in the table you want replayed.

```py
from deephaven import time as dhtu

start_time = dhtu.to_datetime("2022-01-01T00:00:00 NY")
end_time = dhtu.to_datetime("2022-01-01T00:10:00 NY")

replayer = TableReplayer(start_time, end_time)
```

To create the replayed table, use `add_table`.  This method points at a pre-existing table and specifies the column name that contains timestamps:

```py
replayed_table = replayer.add_table(some_table, "Timestamp")
```

From there, use `start` to start the replay:

```py
replayer.start()
```

If `some_table` doesn't have a column of timestamps, here's a simple way to add one:

```py
def create_timestamps(index):
    return dhtu.plus_period(start_time, dhtu.to_period(f"T{index}S"))

some_table = some_table.update(["Timestamp = (DateTime)create_timestamps(i)"])
```

Note that the function above creates timestamps spaced one second apart.